# Aggregation Filter in ES DSL

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the following aggregation filter:

"aggs": {
    "agg_name" : {
      "filter" : { "exists": { "field": "filed_name" } }
    }
  }
}

But I want to write it cleaner using [elasticsearch-dsl](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html). This is the best I could do:

aggs.bucket('agg_name', {"filter": {"exists": {"field": "field_name"}}})

But I know there is a cleaner way. Some failed attempts:

- aggs.bucket('agg_name', A('filter', type='exists',
  field='field_name'))
- aggs.bucket('agg_name', A('filter','exists',
  field='field_name'))
- aggs.bucket('agg_name', A().filter('exists',
  field='field_name'))
- aggs.bucket('agg_name').filter('exists',
  field='field_name')

I'm currently not able to get the right information out of the documentation. Is it possible to write it more DSL-like?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't tried this yet:

```
aggs.A('filter', query.Q('exists', field='field_name'))
```

Some more examples can be found in the [unit test source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/test_elasticsearch_dsl/test_aggs.py#L128-L178)

Comment: Hi Val, I know you posted this a while ago, but could you explain from the point of view of this code snippet?

s = Search(using=client)
s.aggs.bucket('some_bucket_by_day', 'date_histogram', field='time_field', interval='day')
        .metric('some_avg', 'avg', field='some_field')

I would like to filter this somehow like so?
filter='range', **{'time_field': {'gte': 'now-10d'}}

Comment: @jeff_new would you ming posting a new question because code in comments is not really legible, thanks ;-)

Comment: that's a good call.  Here's the new post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056160/elasticsearch-dsl-filter-on-aggregation-and-extended-stats

Comment: Hi Val, forgot to thank you for new post suggestion.  I've tried to go through the unit test source code to no avail.  Any help much appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/test_elasticsearch_dsl/test_aggs.py#L128-L178 is no longer working

Comment: [Working link to the tests](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/main/tests/test_aggs.py#L174-L199) (cannot edit the question atm)

Answer (score 0):

```
s.aggs.bucket("bucket_name", "filter",
                      query.Q("term", fieldname='vale')).metric('field', 'sum', field="whatever")
```

This is what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For a syntax that looks more like other DSL aggregations, you can use

```
s.aggs.bucket("filtered", 
    A("filter", filter=Term(my_field="my_value"))
)
```